# Android studio cannot resolve symbol R when creating a new project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have been trying to create a new project in android studio and I get R. in red saying cannot resolve symbol R. I already installed android-sdk and linked it with android studio. I added android support v4.0 to lib folder. But still a new project gives the above error. Tried synchronizing with gradle, cleaning, rebuilding and invalidate cache and restart. They don't work.

```
package com.example.root.mn;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Mn extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mn);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mn, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Above is the main activity of the project. 
I'm using android studio in linux. I've installed all APIs in sdk. Updated them.

Comment: This can happen because you have some errors in your code, if no error is there try to comment your extra code and run the normal Blank/Empty activity

Comment: most the time it is a problem in any xml layout or values file.

Comment: I did not add or edit any code. I just created the project, ried to build it.

Comment: Then comment you java file code and comment your activity_mn and show only an empty text view like the first time you create your blank activity and then try to run your code

Comment: Import this `import com.example.root.mn.R;`.

Comment: Tried that. But the import itself says cannot resolve symbol R

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment hence posting here.. click on that R and click alt+Enter then click import class. the R file import may look like (in your case) 
import com.example.root.R

Comment: Tried that already. But they don't give an option to import class, when I hit alt+enter.

Comment: try typing it. import com.example.root.R

Comment: Did that already. But the import itself says cannot resolve symbol R